# Error is saving java.sql.Date in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, codec, mongo-java

Not able to save `java.sql.Date` field using `DBCollection.save()`

> Error : CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class java.sql.Date.

while `insert()` method has constructor having DBEncoder field.

```
DBCollection.insert(List<? extends DBObject> documents, WriteConcern aWriteConcern, DBEncoder dbEncoder)
```

But any kind of constructor for `save()` method.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your Date object from java.sql.Date to java.util.Date

```
java.util.Date newDate = new Date(yourSqlDate.getTime());
```

if you don't know when did you use java.sql.Date in your code, I suggest you should try to check if there are any Date variable that is update from SQL statement.

You should not have any problem if you use Mongo 2.x library, but since Mongo 3.x library, seems they removed the java.sql.Date support.